# What property to use for a prebuilt vscode devcontainer

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer, devcontainer

I am currently build a VSCode devcontainer to share with my team.
The container is built on a Gitlab pipeline using `devcontainer build` and pushed on our private registry. Then in the repo we are pulling that container
My question is around the `devcontainer.json` file used for the prebuilt container. It seems I can't find any answer nowhere.

What property can I actually use from the [reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/devcontainerjson-reference) in a `devcontainer build` context? From the doc, they only show a couple from an couple. But what about the others? (especially `settings`)

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the container image from your private registry in the `devcontainer.json`.

`devcontainer.json`

```json
{
  "image": "your-private-registry"
}
```

Ref: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/create-dev-container#_create-a-devcontainerjson-file